# Distinguishing between GUI and programmatic events in WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

As far as I know, it is a quite frequent situation in GUI design that you must react to GUI events (mouse or keyboard interaction with the widgets), but ignore the changes done to the widget values programmatically. Otherwise, unwanted cascaded calls are performed, often leading to infinite loops, because the same event handlers `On...Changed` are invoked every time.

Though it is easy to work around this by means of a flag that you toggle before and after any programmatic change, my question is: is there a built-in way of distinguishing between event handler calls caused by the GUI or program actions ?  (Or even better, a way to disable programmatic changes to raise an event.)

---

I also know that it is possible to avoid implementing the `On...Changed` handlers and instead use alternative handlers such as `On...Clicked`, `On...Scrolled`, `On...KeyPressed`... but this would not be my favorite approach, because these are not the handlers created by default and they are specific to the different widgets.

Comment: Why should this be needed in the first place? Why would code result in a `KeyPressed` event unless it tried to send keystrokes to a control instead of modifying its properties? And if a view or long textbox gets scrolled one way or another, shouldn't the scroll events fire anyway? Updating a UI element's data should be done through data binding which *doesn't* raise UI events

Comment: You'll have to provide specific examples, because what you describe is a rare situation, especially in WPF. Yes, there are a *few* WinForms controls that don't have data binding but there's almost always a better alternative.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: my application(s) use no data binding.

Comment: There's the problem then

Comment: What *is* your case? You'll have to provide specific examples. I repeat, what you describe is an abnormal case - and I've been using WinForms since 2002, WPF for the last 10+ years. What you describe is typically a design issue and tight coupling of logic with UI elements.

Comment: Post the details in the question itself. Data binding avoids the problem entirely. You're asking how to make something meant to mean one thing work in a different way. Why would a programmatic change result in an event in the first place? What component and action does this?

Comment: In the case of radio and checkbox buttons, data binding would solve the problem by modifying the data, not the controls. The controls would be updated in response to the data changes. Call it MVC, MVVM or whatever, the problem becomes a *lot* simpler once you separate presentation from logic, even on WinForms. It does take more work though

Comment: I already explained you need to add the details in the question itself. Especially if you don't like the obvious answers (disable events, decouple view from logic) and want to use some custom technique.  Maybe someone else has found a way to do this in these 20 years but I doubt it. You've already discarded the built-in ways. What you ask will take far more custom work than databinding and/or decoupling

Comment: I can't. Nor can anyone else. Post the details in the question itself. And be prepared for solutions different from the one you assumed. If you don't want to accept what someone with 20 years experience, former MVP and .NET UG founder tells you, make it easy for others to understand your problem and maybe propose their solutions. Perhaps creating your own custom controls, deriving from the controls you want?

Comment: Besides, the `OnXYZ` methods aren't events or event handlers. These aren't the same. The `OnXYZ` methods will always be called before the event itself is raised - in fact, the base method is the one that raises the events. If you don't want to respond to an event, you can remove its event handlers

Comment: So one way to avoid events is to override the `OnXYZ` method and *don't* call the base method. You'll have to override all the controls you need though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: is there a way to distinguish between a call of a Change event handler caused by a GUI interaction or a property set ? .NET, WinForms. Like (C# example) 

        private void checkBoxConcaveCircle_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isProgrammatic()) return;
        }
}

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I found an interesting approach on another SO post, suggesting that it suffices to check if the widget has the focus. I just need to make sure that this is 100% bulletproof.